# Blind Estimation of Signal Parameter and Noise Variance

Tags: random-process, parameter-estimation

Let $y[n]= h*x[n] + w[n]$, where $h$ is an unknown but deterministic parameter, $x[n]$ is a BPSK random variable with equal probability of +1 and -1, $w[n]$ are i.i.d. Gaussian with zero mean and unknown variance . Given $N$ observations find the estimate of $h$, and variance of noise.

$x[n]$ and $w[n]$ are independent.

Comment: If we take average values of $y$, it will eliminate the effect of $w$ but will not help us estimate $h$ because $x$ is not known to you. If we consider average of squared values of $y$,
$
P = \frac{1}{N}\sum_0^{N-1}y^2[n] = \frac{1}{N}\sum_0^{N-1}(h^2x_n^2 + w_n^2 + 2hx_nw_n)
$
The expectation value of above estimator is
$
E(P) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_0^{N-1}(h^2 \times 1 + \sigma^2 + 0) = h^2 + \sigma^2
$
Still you have 2 unknowns with only 1 estimator.

Comment: Can we assume h is not time varying?

Answer (score 1):

### Squaring Method

The input signal $x[n]$ can take two values: $+1$ or $-1$. After being multiplied by $h$, the signal becomes $|h|e^{j\angle h}$ (if $x[n]=+1$) or $|h|e^{j(\pi + \angle h)}$ (if $x[n]=-1$). By squaring this we get, $|h|^2e^{j2\angle h}$. Both points get mapped to this. Now we can pick out the magnitude and phase of $h$. In summary, the steps are:

1. Square $y[n]$ to get $z[n]=y^2[n]$.
2. Get the magnitude, $\hat{|h|}=\sqrt{\bigg|\frac{1}{N}\sum_n z[n]\bigg|}$. It was pointed out in the comments that this is a biased estimate with bias $\sigma^2$, so it is not favorable for a large $\sigma$. I describe another way to estimate $\sigma^2$ (without using $\hat{h}$) so that we can use this $\hat{\sigma}^2$ to remove the bias from $\hat{|h|}$.
3. Get the phase, $\angle h=\frac{1}{2N} \sum_n \angle z[n]$
4. Use $\hat{h}$ to get the noise variance, $\hat{\sigma}^2=\bigg(\frac{1}{N}\sum_n z[n]\bigg)-\hat{h}^2$. This comes from the fact that $E\big[z[n]\big]=h^2+\sigma^2$ (also see the clustering method is a better way to go about this as it does not depend on any other estimates).

*Caveat: This method is valid only for phase offsets within $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$*. Anything beyond that, the received signal becomes indistinguishable and there are multiple phase shifts which could give the same signal.

### Clustering Method

If $h$, can be correctly determined, then you can take hard decisions and calculate the noise variance using the distance of the received symbols from the decision you made.

If $h$ can't be determined right away, then this clustering based estimate of $|h|$ and $\sigma^2$ can be used: We know there should be two clusters ($\pm 1$) so we can use a simple method like k-means (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) with $k=2$. The algorithm is:

1. Run k-means on the received samples and get a list of labels back labeling each sample to either cluster $1$ or $2$. Let $S_1$ be the set of sample indices in cluster $1$ and $S_2$ be the set of sample indices in cluster $2$.
2. Now we are going to take all the points in each cluster, shift them be zero mean and take the variance (this will give us a noise variance estimate for each cluster). Then we will average over all of the cluster noise variance estimates to form the final estimate. $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{\bigg( \text{var}\big(y[n]-E[y[n]] \big)\big|_{n \in S_1} + \text{var}\big(y[n]-E[y[n]] \big)\big|_{n \in S_2} \bigg)}{2}$
3. Now we can take the estimate from step $2$ and subtract off the bias term which we estimated here as $\hat{\sigma}^2$ to get the refined estimate $\hat{|h|}_0=\hat{|h|}-\hat{\sigma}^2$. You could also get $|h|$ using the magnitude of the cluster means, $|\hat{h}|=\frac{\text{E}\big(y[n]\big|_{n \in S_1}\big)+\text{E}\big(y[n]\big|_{n \in S_2}\big)}{2}$.

There is also a way get $\angle h$ from the clusters but it too has the criteria that $\angle h$ must be less than $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ so I will not detail it here.

**Long story short:** $|h|$ and $\sigma^2$ are doable, but $\angle h$ is only doable for some cases.

**Code:** https://github.com/B-William/DSPSE/blob/master/blindEstimationOfSignalParameterAndNoiseVariance.m

Comment: And how would you determine the ML of x without knowing h, wouldn't the value of h appear in the ML of X

Comment: The above answer is being edited

Comment: But squaring the received samples will involve cross product terms between h*x(n) and w(n)... since there is no expectations taken in the answer then these do not disappear...I prefer to take modulus of y(n) , that works better I think

Comment: Also how do you get the variance of noise which is unknown

Comment: The cross terms average to zero since the noise is zero mean. I don't need the noise variance since it doesn't appear in my answer at all. All you need is the received samples (that includes the signal plus noise).

Comment: The question itself is about estimating h and variance of noise

Comment: The cross terms does not average to zero untill we take the expectation, or the sample size is large (so that law of large numbers can be applied)

Comment: I edited once more to clear up confusion and add the noise variance. It'll be interesting to see if others can distinguish beyond those phases but I don't see how just try drawing it out

Comment: In step 2, how will you eliminate effect of noise? $\sqrt{|\frac{1}{N}\sum z[n]|} = \sqrt{|\frac{1}{N}\sum (h^2+w_n^2)|} = \sqrt{|\frac{1}{N}(Nh^2 + \sum w_n^2)|} = \sqrt{|h^2 + W|}$. $W$ is still a finite term unless $N \rightarrow \infty$. Step 2 is an unbiased estimator of $|h|$. Gives me the feeling it is not the correct estimator. Would appreciate if you can educate me, may be I am missing something obvious..

Comment: What about the cross terms between x and w. Since these are finite N observations and there is no expectation over it. I don't think the terms vanish

Comment: I don't think it takes too large of an $N$. Something like $N=100$ would work if I had to guess. But yes, if $N$ is too small, I lose confidence that this method would work.

Comment: I missed the cross terms in my comment (sorry for that - I am not able to edit it for some reason). Coming back to the topic, if $\frac{1}{N}\sum w_n^2$ will be $\sigma^2$ even with $N \rightarrow \infty$. I don't think it will become small for $N=100$ or even $N=1000$. May be I will try to simulate when I am free.

Comment: So my point is that the question is a very difficult problem because of 2 unknowns. That is in any digital communication system, we send pilot symbols to estimate $h$. Your answer was a good attempt but step 2 is the flaw I think (may be I am wrong too!). I already indicated about this in the comment below question yesterday.

Comment: Yes, it is a biased estimator. The question does not say it needs to be unbiased. I provide an alternative method to using clustering to get the noise variance and magnitude of $h$ but the phase still requires $\angle h$ less than $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$.